# Swift Storyboarding and Hello World

Tags: xcode, swiftui, storyboard

i am new to swift and haven't taken any development courses yet for this purpose, although I was running through some tutorials on how to create a quick app, and there's one lingering question that keeps pestering me.

when you create an swiftui, or a storyboard single-view app more specifically, where is the application entry point?  I noticed that there is a "storyboard" entry point by default, and you can actually have many of these if you happen to create more storyboards in your single-view application, however there's nothing to me that specifies that that this is the exact entry-point for the application when it launches.  Is it by convention that a storyboard named "LaunchScreen.storyboard" gets loaded first?  cause I moved it to a subdirectory (by creating a new group), and it still did its thing.

Moreover, I can't figure out why this view-controller runs "ContentView" in a SwiftUI, or loads "Main.storyboard" in a storyboard app.  Like where does it specify it?  where can I change this behavious?  I can't locate it in the code anywhere.

I was experimenting earlier by creating a SwiftUI single-view app, and getting it to not load "contentview" (the hello world example), and instead actually go to another view or storyboard, but no luck.  Any good references I check on the matter?

p.s.  using the latest version of xcode (11.5) and macos.

Answer (score 1):

For UIKit and storyboards, there is a entry point("the arrow") that points to the view that the user will land on once the application is loaded. The LaunchScreen.storyboard is the view that the user sees while the main application is loading. It is only there to replace the default plain white view you see when you are loading an application that may take a while to load. In SwiftUI, it also has a LaunchScreen.storyboard with the exact same purpose, but if you go to the SceneDelegate.swift file and look around, you will find this block of code which declares and tells the application to show ContentView once the application is done loading.

```
let contentView = ContentView()

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

By replacing `ContentView()` with another view, you can change your root view.